# how can I "process" text from tee before it is sent to a file

Tags: bash, shell, debian

Is there a way to process text from tee before it sent to a file?

For example, if a program outputted the following lines:

```
stack 11
stack 22
stack 33
serverfault
serverfault
stack 44
```

How could I send only the lines that contain "stack" to a file, while still displaying the original output from the program via stdout?

I'm not sure whether it would even be possible to do this using tee, so I am open to any other suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: `cat file && grep stack file > newfile`?

Comment: @BroSlow sorry I had made a mistake while writing the original description, this would be for filtering output from a program and not a file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display the full output of myprogram on the terminal while saving filtered output to a file:

```
myprogram | tee /dev/tty | grep stack >out
```

If you didn't want to send the full output to your terminal but instead wanted to process it with something else, say `someotherprogram`, then we can use bash's process substitution:

```
myprogram | tee >(grep stack >out) | someotherprogram
```

`someotherprogram` receives the full output of `myprogram` on its stdin while only filtered output is saved in `out`.

Comment: @KeithReynolds Thanks.  Just to clarify for those reading this, your tty is always `/dev/tty`.

Comment: how to preserve original stdout colors in tee's output `/dev/tty`?

Comment: @minseong  By itself, `tee /dev/tty` does not remove any colors.  As an example, try `echo a b c | grep --color=always b | tee /dev/tty >/dev/null`.  You should see color output from `tee /dev/tty`.   The issue is likely that some programs may produce color only when sending output to a terminal, not a pipeline.  You may be able to override this with an option to `myprogram`.  For `grep`, that option is `--color=always`.

Comment: The solution I used in the end was `script -q /dev/null myprogram | tee /dev/tty | someotherprogram`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use tee  but it does everything you want it to do

```
#!/bin/bash

cat |
while read line ; do 
    echo $line
    echo $line |grep stack >> outfile.txt
done
```

Comment: hello, sorry I had made a mistake while writing the original description, this would be for filtering output from a program and not a file

Comment: @lacrosse1991 Just replace `cat` with the program whose output you are capturing, or pipe the output of that program to this script.

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to Keith's answer, but doesn't rely on any external tools (except for tee, of course)

```
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ man tee|cat > stackHelp.file
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ wc -l stackHelp.file
      33 stackHelp.file
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ cat stackHelp.file|while read i;do if [[ $i =~ "file" ]];then echo "$i"|tee -a stackHelp.out;else echo "$i";fi;done|wc -l
      33
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ grep file stackHelp.out
in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.
-a      Append the output to the files rather than overwriting them.
file  A pathname of an output file.
AirBoxOmega:~ d$
```

You can put the while loop after any command, and then just use whatever keyword you were looking for. In my example I'm using the text from the tee manpage.

Here's the code pretty printed, though it's relatively simple (Yes, it's a useless cat, but it's demonstrating that a while loop can read the output of a command not just read in from a file).

```
cat stackHelp.file | while read i; do
    if [[ $i =~ "file" ]]; then
        echo "$i" | tee -a stackHelp.out;
    else
        echo "$i";
    fi;
done
```